# SQL count, use only last record

Tags: sql, count

can someone help me about counting rows in sql. I have a table, archive, in which I have bank account and status of that account. One account can have and usually have more records, in my count I have to use last record, not records before. Example:

```
account         status
5552222           A
5552222           B
5552222           A
**5552222           B**
4445896           A
4445896           B
**4445896           A**
```

I have to use this who are bold. Based on this there is one B(blocked) and one A(active) account. I have column datetime, which can tell me what is last record. I just need query to count that

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do. Describe it more precisely, including example results.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to count based on the most current row for an account:

```
SELECT tab.status,
   COUNT(*)
FROM tab JOIN
 (
   SELECT account, MAX(datetime) AS maxdate
   FROM tab
   GROUP BY account
 ) AS dt
ON tab.account = dt.account
AND tab.datetime = dt.maxtime
GROUP BY tab.Status
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)  
FROM yourTable
WHERE Status='B'
```

or

```
WHERE AccountName LIKE '%B'
```

**Edit: After OP modified the question to include the table data.**

So, the problem is that the same account number can occur multiple times, and you want to count on the basis of last status of the account.
If the account is currently blocked, you would like to count it, irrespective of the number of times it gets blocked earlier.

Assumption: You have a date type column in your table which shows the date when the record's (with new status value) was inserted (or it may be an identity field which keeps track of the order of records created in the table)

The query will be:

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
FROM
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
         acNumber, 
         (  SELECT Max(identityField_or_dateField) 
            FROM tableName t  
            WHERE t.acNumber = t2.acNumber AND Status='B')
    FROM tableName t2
    WHERE 
         (  SELECT Max(identityField_or_dateField) 
            FROM tableName t  
            WHERE t.acNumber = t2.acNumber AND Status='B') IS NOT NULL
) tblAlias
```

---

*Glad to help! Please remember to accept the answer if you found it helpful.*

Comment: It will count all rows with Status='B'. In my example above it would be 3 blocked accounts, and actually it's only one: account 5552222 which last state is blocked.